# Why is the function prototype inside a different function block?

Tags: c, prototype

I am trying to understand C, by going through K&R. I have trouble understanding this code for two functions found in the book:

```
void qsort(int v[], int left, int right){
int i, last;

void swap(int v[], int i, int j);

if (left >= right)
    return;

swap(v, left, (left+right)/2);

last = left;

for ( i = left+1; i<=right; i++)
    if (v[i]<v[left])
        swap(v,++last, i);

swap(v,left,last);
qsort(v,left,last-1);
qsort(v,last+1,right);
}


void swap(int v[], int i, int j){

    int temp;

    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}
```

These two function perform a quicksort on a given array. In the main function I created an int array and called qsort. It compiled fine and ran fine. My question is, why is the **prototype** for swap() put in the function qsort() and not before main()?

Comment: It can be done both ways. I suppose this is done to put the prototype in a scope, not that it matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prototype should be added before the actual function is used for first time. 
In this case, I do not think its a general practice to have prototype in `qsort()` function, however, it still serves the purpose. The prototype for `swap()` could also be added before `main()` too, don't think it will make a difference.

Comment: This is incorrect. The prototype for `swap()` could **not** be added in `main()`, as it must be declared before it's used in `qsort()`. It is a strange place to put the prototype, but the only other place it could be legally put would be before `swap()`.

Answer (score 5):

You write a function prototype so that the compiler knows that function exists, and can use it. `swap()` is used inside `qsort()`, so it must appear before the line it is used. In this case, the `swap()` prototype is declared inside the `qsort()` function, but it could as well be declared before the function itself. Or you could define `swap()` before `qsort()` and remove the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Placing function prototypes in the definitions of other functions enforces the principle of
least privilege by restricting proper function calls to the functions in which the prototypes appear.